# ssrs rdl text box expression concatenation string and field

Tags: reporting-services, concatenation, rdl

I have several ssrs rdl reports where I am trying to concatenate text then a data set field then text again and it is displayed as a bar code.

Here is the expression:

```
="*" & Fields!barcodenum.Value & "*"
```

Example data for *200145* would look like:

[image]

The report was built with BI in VS 2015. The data set returns the correct data as verified by the query designer.

When I run the report from the 'preview' in VS it displays the correct information for the bar code field.

When the report is published to the SSRS server, 2008R2, it only displays the two stars and no field data.

[image]

The field is formatted as a varchar(8).

Am I concatenating the field correctly? Is there a different way to concatenate this?

Any help would be very greatly excepted.

Comment: Try ="*" & CSTR(Fields!barcodenum.Value)  & "*" Add the * in there.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!
But how do I mark that as the answer?

Comment: I just pasted my comment into the answer, you can mark it answered now.

Answer (score 16):

Try `="*" & CSTR(Fields!barcodenum.Value) & "*"` Your barcodenum field is probably an INT and needs to be converted to a string for this to work.